# Load RandomForestModel for use in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I trained and saved (parquet format) a pretty heavy random forest model using Spark mllib 1.3.0

I wanted to use it for real time classification with a Spark streaming job, but facing few difficulties, mainly related to the size of the model and the necessity to send it to workers.

For now, I see 3 solutions, none of which is ideal:

- Load it on driver side, send it to worker on every computed micro batch. Sample code:

  ```scala
  val model = RandomForestModel.load(sc, path)
  stream.map(smthg => model.predict(...))
  ```

  Problem here is that it serializes and sends model on every batch. For info, I had to set spark.akka.frameSize greater than 50MB in order to execute without error. This is obviously not sustainable
- Load model on each worker. In Spark 1.3, there seems to be no way to get the current SparkContext, so I have to create a new one for each worker to be able to load the model. That means extra CPU needed on the cluster for first micro batch / job iteration
- Execute prediction on driver side:

  ```scala
  val model = RandomForestModel.load(sc, path)
  stream
    .map(smthg => stuff)
    .foreachRDD(rdd => model.predict(rdd))
  ```

  With the drawback of not being able to scale well, as everything happens on the driver side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the last approach doesn't execute on the driver and in practice is [no different than the first one](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/393db655c3c43155305fbba1b2f8c48a95f18d93/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/treeEnsembleModels.scala#L341).

```
def predict(features: RDD[Vector]): RDD[Double] = features.map(x => predict(x))
```

Random forest model is not distributed and serializable so you can use standard tools to write:

```
import java.io._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel

val model: RandomForestModel = ???

val os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/rf"))
os.writeObject(model)
os.close()
```

and read it later:

```
val is  = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/tmp/rf")
val model = is.readObject().asInstanceOf[RandomForestModel]
is.close
```

but this approach is not portable to new ML API so in practice it makes more sense to tune your pipeline to reduce model size.